# How can I make this a callable utils function that contains a hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client

I'm currently using Apollo Client's `useQuery` and `useMutation` hooks to perform the same function in several different components. Instead of repeating the logic, I would like to create a helper function that can keep the logic in a single place.

The problem with this, is `useQuery` and `useMutation` being hooks mean they can't just live in a separate file as functions, but instead need to be valid React function components.

I started trying to make something functional but starting to think this might not be able to be done.

```
  export function HandleFollow (props) {
      const [useFollowUser, { followedData, followError }] = useMutation(FOLLOW_USER);
      useFollowUser({ variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: "userIDxyz"}, onCompleted: props.handleUserFollow(user, isFollowingAuthor)})
  }
```

Is it possible to use util/helper functions with React Hooks? Thanks in advance!

When creating the below, I'm receiving `"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."` and I can't figure out why.

I think that may be due to calling this from inside a function, but I can't figure out how to avoid that.

```
export function useHandleFollow(props) {
  const { user, isFollowingUser } = props
  const [useFollowUser, { followedData, followError }] = useMutation(FOLLOW_USER);
  const [useUnfollowUser, { unfollowedData, unfollowedError }] = useMutation(UNFOLLOW_USER);
  const [followSuccess, setFollowSuccess] = useState(false)
  
  if(!isFollowingUser){
    useFollowUser({ variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id}, onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)})
  }else{
    useUnfollowUser({ variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id}, onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)})
  }
  return followSuccess
}
```

And when I call this right away in my component (instead of calling from inside a function), it continues to infinitely re-render:

Here's some more complete code from the component

in Home.js:

```
const followed = useHandleFollow({ user: author, isFollowingAuthor })


export default  posts = (props) =>{
  let { post, excludeUser = false } = props
  let { author } = post
  let { date, things, isFollowingAuthor } = post
  let { profile_picture } = author
  let currentUser = auth().currentUser
  
  const [followed] = useHandleFollow({ user: author, isFollowingAuthor })
  
  return ()
}
```

And this is in follow.js, which I'm importing as `import { useHandleFollow } from...`

```
export function useHandleFollow(props) {
  const { user, isFollowingUser } = props
  const [followUser, { followedData, followError }] = useMutation(FOLLOW_USER);
  const [unfollowUser, { unfollowedData, unfollowedError }] = useMutation(UNFOLLOW_USER);
  const [followSuccess, setFollowSuccess] = useState(false)
  if(!isFollowingUser){
    followUser({ variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id}, onCompleted: () => setFollowSuccess(true)})
  }else{
    unfollowUser({ variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id}, onCompleted: () => setFollowSuccess(true)})
  }
  return [followSuccess]
}
```

Comment: Plz provide a demo so we can inspect your codes and see what exactly you're trying to achive

Comment: So for the `re-render` issue you need to see why `the props` or some of the `hooks` are changing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is! You can create your own custom react hooks. React hooks use a rather simple naming convention, "use-" prefix.

```
export function useHandleFollow(props) {
  const [useFollowUser, { followedData, followError }] = useMutation(
    FOLLOW_USER
  );
  useFollowUser({
    variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: "userIDxyz" },
    onCompleted: props.handleUserFollow(user, isFollowingAuthor)
  });
}
```

[Only Call Hooks from React Functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

> **Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.** Instead, you can:
>
> - ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> - ✅ Call Hooks from
>   custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them [on the next page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)).
>
> By following this rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a
> component is clearly visible from its source code.

On the next page is an [Extracting a Custom Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook) section!

> **A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use”
> and that may call other Hooks.**

## Edit

> Still receiving invalid hook usage.

```
export function useHandleFollow(props) {
  const { user, isFollowingUser } = props;
  const [useFollowUser, { followedData, followError }] = useMutation(
    FOLLOW_USER
  );
  const [useUnfollowUser, { unfollowedData, unfollowedError }] = useMutation(
    UNFOLLOW_USER
  );
  const [followSuccess, setFollowSuccess] = useState(false);

  if (!isFollowingUser) {
    useFollowUser({
      variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id },
      onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)
    });
  } else {
    useUnfollowUser({
      variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id },
      onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)
    });
  }
  return followSuccess;
}
```

I think the issue here is the naming of the "mutate" function, which you've inconveniently named just like another React Hook. The React Hook linting rules are interpreting the `if (!isFollowingUser) {...}` as conditionally calling a hook, which is invald. Give them a non-React-hook name. `useFollowUser` to `followUser` and `useUnfollowUser` to `unfollowUser`.

```
export function useHandleFollow(props) {
  const { user, isFollowingUser } = props;
  const [followUser, { followedData, followError }] = useMutation(
    FOLLOW_USER
  );
  const [unfollowUser, { unfollowedData, unfollowedError }] = useMutation(
    UNFOLLOW_USER
  );
  const [followSuccess, setFollowSuccess] = useState(false);

  if (!isFollowingUser) {
    followUser({
      variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id },
      onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)
    });
  } else {
    unfollowUser({
      variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id },
      onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)
    });
  }
  return followSuccess;
}
```

> Still render looping

`useHandleFollow` is called each render cycle. I think your custom hook triggers the render looping when it is unconditionally updating the `followSuccess` state in each branch of logic.

```
export function useHandleFollow(props) {
  ...
  const [followSuccess, setFollowSuccess] = useState(false);

  // setFollowSuccess(true) called always
  if (!isFollowingUser) {
    followUser({
      variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id },
      onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)
    });
  } else {
    unfollowUser({
      variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id },
      onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

This ends up updating state *every* time the hook is called. You should place a condition on when you want this effect to be run, i.e. place *that* code block in an `useEffect` hook with a callback dependency on `isFollowingUser`. The effect callback will only run when the `isFollowingUser` value changes, not whenever the component renders.

```
export function useHandleFollow(props) {
  const { user, isFollowingUser } = props;
  const [followUser, { followedData, followError }] = useMutation(
    FOLLOW_USER
  );
  const [unfollowUser, { unfollowedData, unfollowedError }] = useMutation(
    UNFOLLOW_USER
  );
  const [followSuccess, setFollowSuccess] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFollowingUser) {
      followUser({
        variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id },
        onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)
      });
    } else {
      unfollowUser({
        variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id },
        onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)
      });
    }
  }, [isFollowingUser]);

  return followSuccess;
}
```

> Should I be returning something, like a set method or something, to
> accept new props? Otherwise, how do I end up calling the hook with
> those new props?

You only need to return updater function from hooks if you need them. React hooks are called each render cycle, so if you pass props to them then they will always receive the current props.

Comment: Hi Drew, this seems like the right track but I'm still receiving the error. I updated the question with the new naming convention (use in function name), but still receiving that error. Is there anything I should be doing in the imports or anything? Thank you!

Comment: @DanFein Looks like you named your mutation functions poorly and React thinks they are React Hooks. Updated answer with explanation. As for the render looping you may want/need to place the `if (!isFollowingUser) {...}` if-block in a `useEffect` with a dependency so you are unconditionally updating state. Can you include a full example of your component code using your custom hook?

Comment: Hi Drew - I've updated with more complete component code. I have to admit, I feel now I'm confused with how I should even be using the hook. Since I'm using it to make the queries, and be reusable, how do I actually use it? Should I be returning something, like a set method or something, to accept new props? Otherwise, how do I end up calling the hook with those new props? Thank you a ton!

Comment: @DanFein React hooks are called each render cycle, and if you pass props to them then they will always receive the current props. You want to conditionally call your query mutators (*and from what I can tell*) based upon the value of `isFollowingUser` changing. If multiple renders occur but the user is still followed then there is likely no need to re-query. Does this make sense?

Comment: I think I've got it now, you are rock! Basically, I didn't understand just how many times each hook was being called! I created the `useEffect` where the dependency is a "user" that should be followed. Essentially, I set the initial state for that `user` to false, and on click I change it to the user, and after they're followed/unfollowed I change that state back to false. This seems to work! I don't know how to do it on monitoring for a changing value of isFollowingUser without the infinite re-render (e.g. if it's true and then a user goes to unfollow, now it's false, so it would re-run?)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Custom Hook` to achieve your goal by declaring a function which starts with `use` like this:

```
  export function useHandleFollow (props) {
      const [useFollowUser, { followedData, followError }] = useMutation(FOLLOW_USER);
      useFollowUser({ variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: "userIDxyz"}, onCompleted: props.handleUserFollow(user, isFollowingAuthor)})
  }
```

remember that all the `React Hooks Rule` is also applied to `Custom Hooks`.

Comment: Hi Taghi, this seems like the right track but I'm still receiving the error. I updated the question with the new naming convention (use in function name), but still receiving that error. Is there anything I should be doing in the imports or anything? Thank you!

Comment: @DanFein `Custom Hooks` Can Only be called inside a `React Functional Component` or within `Another Custom Hook`. You can't just call it randomly inside a function. if you need to call it from another function, just make sure that function is also a custom hook