# How can I properly call this custom hook, and avoid infinite re-renders?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client and wanted to make re-usable calls, so I was recommended to use Custom Hooks. I've tried but don't think I'm implementing them properly as they're re-rendering indefinitely and I can't figure out if this will actually do what I want.

I would like to, from another component, call useHandleFollow to call either `useFollowUser` or `useUnfollowUser` which will perform one of two useMutations, based on the isFollowingUser conditional.

```
export function useHandleFollow(props) {
  const { user, isFollowingUser } = props
  const [useFollowUser, { followedData, followError }] = useMutation(FOLLOW_USER);
  const [useUnfollowUser, { unfollowedData, unfollowedError }] = useMutation(UNFOLLOW_USER);
  const [followSuccess, setFollowSuccess] = useState(false)
  if(!isFollowingUser){
    useFollowUser({ variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id}, onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)})
  }else{
    useUnfollowUser({ variables: { fromId: auth().currentUser.uid, toId: user.id}, onCompleted: setFollowSuccess(true)})
  }
  return followSuccess
}
```

I then tried to instantiate that like this, from the body of another component:

```
const followed = useHandleFollow({ user: author, isFollowingAuthor })
```

But that triggers an endless loop. Really, I want to only call this on a user's click, so have a function like this:

```
const handleUserFollow = (user) => {
  useHandleFollow(user, true)
}
```

How should I be going about this instead? Thank you in advance!

Edit: The proposed similar question is a different problem, this question is a separate issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make this a callable utils function that contains a hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547620/how-can-i-make-this-a-callable-utils-function-that-contains-a-hook)

Comment: No as that question led me to implement this, but this issue is a result of that implementation. It’s a separate issue.

Comment: when you use or run `useFollowUser` or `useUnfollowUser` function does that affect the `isFollowingUser` prop?

Comment: Nope, no change to that. Am I maybe instantiating the hook incorrectly?